# Display a view block on multiple pages

Tags: 8, blocks, group

I have a block that I want to display on `/group/*`. That is working, but it is also displaying the block on `/group/*/edit`which is pretty annoying and unwanted.

Is there a way to restrict that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't list all the groups' paths (if there are too many) you can use an extra module [Block Exclude Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_exclude_pages).

Although when it comes to Edit pages it's customary to use the Administration theme for editing content instead of the default theme. This way the blocks meant to be displayed to visitors wouldn't appear when creating/editing content.

You can change this at the bottom of the `Appearance` page: **Use the administration theme when editing or creating content**.

You could also use a lot more complex solution depending on your project needs, like [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) or [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) that take over the Blocks layout configuration and allow for a lot more control.